# WP CALENDAR start time

Tags: fullcalendar

i want to remove the start time for events in the calendar 
Have tried the following 
    .fc-view-month .fc-event-time{ 
    display : none; 
    }

And
    .fc-event-time{ 
    display : none; 
    } 
But the time for events still show in the calendar

how can i remove the start time so i only get the event to show on the calendar

Answer (score 0):

Where did you place `.fc-event-time{ display : none; }`?
I pasted it in the style.css of the theme that I'm using and that worked perfectly fine! No start time appears anymore!